# How to rotate a bitmap with AffineTransform

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple program that displays a bitmap zombie picture and then rotates it around using AffineTransform and Thread. I followed the example I had to accomplish this, but whenever I run the program  the zombie bitmap just rotates once and stops. Also, for some reason when I painted the zombie bitmap, the image is partially off the screen along the y-axis.

So my questions are: why is the bitmap not rotating and why is the bitmap off the screen.

Code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;// Graphics class
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.net.*;//URL navigation
import javax.swing.*;//JFrame
import java.util.*;//Toolkit

public class BitMapZombies2 extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private Image zombieOneRight;
    Thread zombieRun;


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new BitMapZombies2();
    }

    public BitMapZombies2()
    {
        super("Bit Map Zombies..RUN FOR YOUR LIFE!!!");
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Toolkit Zkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        zombieOneLeft = Zkit.getImage(getURL("_images/_production_images/zombie_1_left_75h.png"));
        zombieOneRight = Zkit.getImage(getURL("_images/_production_images/zombie_1_right_75h.png"));

        zombieRun = new Thread(this);
        zombieRun.start();

    }

    AffineTransform zombieIdentity = new AffineTransform();

    private URL getURL(String filename)
    {
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return url;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics z)
    {
        Graphics2D z2d = (Graphics2D) z;
        AffineTransform ZombiePowered = new AffineTransform();

        z2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        z2d.fillRect(0,0, 800, 600);

        ZombiePowered.setTransform(zombieIdentity);
        ZombiePowered.rotate(2,37.5,37.5);
        z2d.drawImage(zombieOneRight,ZombiePowered,this);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Thread zT = Thread.currentThread();
        while (zT == zombieRun)
        {
            try
            {

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }


        }
```

Appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting your code:

```
    AffineTransform ZombiePowered = new AffineTransform();//Create an Id. transform
    ZombiePowered.setTransform(zombieIdentity);//Set it as a copy of an Id. transform
    ZombiePowered.rotate(2, 37.5, 37.5);//Concatenate the rotation with the Id. transform
    z2d.drawImage(zombieOneRight, ZombiePowered, this);//Apply the rotation
```

So your always rotating 2rads your image. If you do this assignment at the end of the paint method:

```
            zombieIdentity = ZombiePowered;
```

the next time you paint the image it will be rotate 2rads more.
About the issues with the position, take a look at rotate javadoc:

> Concatenates this transform with a transform that rotates coordinates
>   around an anchor point. This operation is equivalent to translating
>   the coordinates so that the anchor point is at the origin (S1), then
>   rotating them about the new origin (S2), and finally translating so
>   that the intermediate origin is restored to the coordinates of the
>   original anchor point (S3).
>
> This operation is equivalent to the following sequence of calls:
>
> ```
>  translate(anchorx, anchory);      // S3: final translation
>  rotate(theta);                    // S2: rotate around anchor
>  translate(-anchorx, -anchory);    // S1: translate anchor to origin
> ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank took care of the rotation issue, I need to do a bit more research to understand the comments but now I have someplace to start. The image still displays partially off screen, even with 0 rotation.

Comment: With the rotate working I decided to use this information and apply it to a translate. I replaced the ZombiePowered.rotate(2, 37.5, 37.5); with ZombiePowered.translate(5,0);. I still had motion, this time across the screen, but one thing I did notice was the first time the image is drawn the location is much greater than 5 pixels from the 0,0 point. So, how can I get the image to start at 0,0 and then translate it 5 pixels at a time. Also, the image is still sitting high on the y-axis with part of the image sitting off screen. Any idea how to fix that or what may be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your transformation, you need to apply it to the graphics context...

```
public void paint(Graphics z)
{
    //...
    z2d.setTransform(ZombiePowered);
    //...
}
```

Once you apply a transformation, it will effect everything painted to the `Graphics` context after it so you need to reset it or referse it.  There's lots of ways to do this, but the simplest would be to create a copy of the `Graphics` context and simply `dispose` of it when you no longer need it...

```
public void paint(Graphics z)
{
    Graphics2D z2d = (Graphics2D) z.create();
    //...
    z2d.dispose();
}
```

Also, this is just me, but I'd be creating a new instance of the `AffineTransform`, these things are to easy to completely screw up...